# Control access to certain columns of table?

Tags: sql-server-2005, database

Is it possible to control access to certain column of table and allow access to only particular column in MS-SQL server? If yes how? IF no Is there any alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Server does in fact support column level permissions.

See [this article](http://www.sqlserver2005tutorial.com/Tutorial-Learn-Implementing-Column-Level-Security.html) for details of how to apply them via the SSMS UI.

Answer (score 2):

IMO the correct way to do this is to use views and secure the view to the people who can access it.

See here on [Ode To Code](http://odetocode.com/code/299.aspx) for a better example.

say you have a table (`the_table`)  with three cols (a, b & c) you can create a view that has only the cols your require

```
create view show_colc_view 
as 
  select c from  the_table
```

You can then secure the people who have CRUD privilege on the both the table and view.

so the people concerned can do this:

```
select * from  show_colc_view
```

but not

```
select * from  the_table
```

Comment: Why do you say this is "The correct way" when column level permissions exist for exactly this?

Comment: @Martin--this isn't the first time where I've heard that proper security technique is to create views and only allow access to those views.  Of course, this is an optimal *security* solution, and not always one for ease of programming.  But if you're using Oracle for example, views provide fine-grained security that are much easier to maintain than a list of "what groups get what column."  But don't take my word for it.  Foundational papers like this do the talking:  http://www.springerlink.com/content/y481847v74038211/

Comment: Here, a better and more accessible piece of info: (slide 43 of an OWASP presentation)--Using a combination of row-level security + views is optimal.  http://www.denimgroup.com/media/pdfs/OWASP_SanAntonio_February2006_SecondMostSecureDatabase.pdf

Comment: @avgvstvs - That second link is talking about row level security not column level. I take your point that for administrative ease Views can allow you to easily define groups of columns however.

Comment: @Martin Exactly--Column-level controls are not discussed in that OWASP presentation for precisely the administration reasons I discussed above--and agreed to by you.  If you deny access to ALL tables but through views--you just created an easily maintainable & auditable whitelist to your data.

Answer (score 0):

Create a view with the allowed columns, and grant the user access to the view only..

```
table columns: a, b, c, d, e, f

CREATE VIEW allowed as SELECT a,b,c FROM table;
GRANT SELECT ON allowed to <user>;
```

then the user should query the view and not the table:

```
SELECT * from allowed;
```

and they'll only see columns a, b and c (not d, e or f)